# How can we use value from model in background image tag of razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm getting the image name from database.I need to append it in the view I tried many things but its working.

```
@foreach(var item in @Model.images)
{
    <li id="cont2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
        <a class="each_jobs epub_bg"  background: "'/Content/img/'+@item.image+'.png'" no-repeat scroll center center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="EPUB"></a>
    </li >
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background` should be used in `style` property like following. And you also missed `url` to add `background`.

```
@{ item.image = item.image + ".png"; }
<a class="each_jobs epub_bg"  style="background: url('/Content/img/@item.image') 
no-repeat scroll center center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" 
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="EPUB"></a>
```

Comment: It's not working.. :-( I tried url('~/Content/img/'+@item.image+'.png'). That's also not working

Comment: Still its not working.. I changed it to @item.image also.. that also is not working

Comment: Are you confirm about location of image? Check in developer console.

Comment: Ya.. I'm sure.. Should I add ('~/Content/img/@item.image')??

Comment: No, ('/Content/img/@item.image') should work. Are you using `firebug`? What is it saying? Failed to load the given URL?